# Why does this regexp match, but not location / in NGINX

Tags: nginx, regex

I basically have those two locations in NGINX (Return codes added for debugging purpose)

```
location / {
    return 401;
}


location ~ "^/(assets|((de|en|es|fr|it|zh|ru)-[a-z]{3}))" {
    return 402;
}
```

The idea is to return 401 on GET https://www.example.com/, but it always returns 402

How can that be?

```
$ http https://www.example.com/ --print Hh
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/1.0.3

HTTP/1.1 402 Payment Required
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 176
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 07 Jun 2021 10:07:37 GMT
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

I also tested the regexp on https://nginx.viraptor.info/ and it does not match a [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/) request, so I believe it should run into the `location /` block?

EDIT: Before that I have some

```
rewrite ^/$ /de-abc/;
```

Comment: `location /` only matches the request if no other `location` matches it. Is this the entire contents of the `server` block? If you want to specifically match `/`, use `location = /`.

Comment: It's not the entire contents, I can try to boil it down - but why does it look like the regexp match?

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details. Clearly the original request does not match that `location`, but we have no idea how the original request is processed.

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`

Answer (score 0):

The reasons was a rewrite which was not a redirect earlier in the config

```
rewrite ^/$ /de-abc/;
```

I intented to use

```
rewrite ^/$ /de-abc/ redirect;
```